# Segmentation fault (core dumped) using matplotlib on Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Tags: python, 16.04, ubuntu-mate, matplotlib

I recently installed on my machine (an old imac) Ubuntu Mate 16.04. When I try to run a python script from terminal I get the error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The same script works perfectly in other machines and used to work well in my machine when it mounted Xubuntu 14.04.
This is probably a problem with python in Ubuntu Mate 16.04 and in particular with matplotlib: my script gives me the error when trying to draw a plot using pyplot. 
Other python scripts that don't use matplotlib work perfectly.

According to my terminal, matplotlib is the newest version (1.5.1-1ubuntu1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be related to the backend you are using.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091993/list-of-all-available-matplotlib-backends) you can find how to get a list of avaliable backends.

To use a backend just call matplotlib.use("chosen-backend") at the start of your script.

Alternatively I suggest to try and use [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) and install all packages (including matplotlib) locally, using pip.

Comment: This solved my problem.  I had to change the backend AND remove the extension from the file name of the plot that I was trying to save.  I can't choose the figures' format now, but at least they get saved.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.
Turns out the order in which to import your modules was the problem.
If I import all matplotlib modules first, problem was solved

Comment: Yes. Very strange!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, you can change the `chosen-backend` or install `qt5` as suggested in these issues:

- [`matplolib#9294`: Segmentation fault (core dumped) when import matplotlib.pyplot](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9294/)
- [`matplotlib#6531`: Segmentation fault with any backend (matplotlib 1.4.3 and 1.5.1) when calling pyplot.show()](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6531/).

Installing `qt5` worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

you need to delete all opencv related packages first, and then reinstall the 4.2.0.32 version of headless opencv:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless==4.2.0.32`
```

Comment: Hmmm... How does OpenCV come into play here? The OP hasn't mentioned anything about it and it isn't that it gets installed with Matplotlib or something.